# Normal distribution, finding the lowest grade point

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

> The grades on the final examination in a large statistics section are
> normally distributed with a mean of $78$ and a standard deviation of $8$.
>
> The teacher wants to give the grade $A$ to $10\%$ of the students.
>
> What is the lowest grade point that can be designated an $A$ on the
> final?

I tried to find the $z$-score and probability, but I couldn't understand what the question was asking. I need some help on what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Given that $78 \pm 8$ is $70,86$, what is the chance that a student scores between 70 and 86, inclusive?

Comment: @user2661923 I found the limits. Should I need to find probability? How do I find the lowest grade? Could you please explain clearly?

Comment: Edit your query to : [1] Show the chance that a student scores between 70,86 inclusive. [2] scores between 78 and 86 inclusive. [3] scores between 87 and 94 inclusive.  try to consult your math book, notes to discover the value of $x$ so that the chance that the student scores between $x$ and $100$ is $0.10$.  In order to receive help, you will have to show work in your query.  Personally, I can't help anyway, because I don't know a standard deviation from a *giraffe*.

Answer (score 1):

**You want the 90th percentile** of the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=78,\sigma=8).$ You can find the
answer by standardizing and using printed normal CDF
tables. You will find that the 90th percentile of
the standard normal distribution is about 1.28.

In R, you can find the answer directly, using the
normal quantile function `qnorm` as follows:

```
qnorm(.9, 78, 8)
[1] 88.25241
```

If the lowest A is 89, then very slightly fewer
than 10% may get A's. If the lowest A is 88, then
very slightly more than 105 may get A's.

**Simulation of a hypothetical class** of size $n = 100.$
In any one particular such class there may be gaps
or ties at or near 88 and 89, making it impossible
to be fair and also to give *exactly* 10% A's.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = round(rnorm(100, 78, 8)
quantile(x, .9)
90% 
 90 

sort(x)
  [1] 60 61 61 62 63 63 65 65 65 66 66 66 66 66 67 67 67 68 68 69
 [21] 69 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 71 72 72 72 73 73 73 74 74 75 75 75
 [41] 75 75 76 76 76 76 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 78 78 78 78 78 78
 [61] 78 79 79 79 79 79 80 80 80 81 81 81 81 81 82 82 82 82 83 83
 [81] 84 84 84 85 85 86 86 87 88 90 90 90 90 90 91 91 91 92 92 95
```

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer. But why do we find 90th percentile of the distribution?

Comment: 90th percentile has 90% below, leaving 10% above.